# How to change milliseconds to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssS" format?

Tags: android, time, format, simpledateformat

I am getting time in milliseconds ("1369807669") format from JSON and i have to change that in "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssS" format ... How can i do it??

I used this code but i am getting different time not the actual time.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
DateTime = df.format(millis);
```

But i am getting time as "1970-12-23'T'12:54:32+0000" which is wrong...

I should get time something like this "2013-05-29'T'12:06:53+0000"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have `seconds` not `milliseconds` you should multipy your seconds `* 1000`

Comment: Oops!! my bad... Thanks for the help though...

Answer (score 0):

check this for your current date and check with your json milliseconds also

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

          df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String currentDate = formatter.format(new Date(System
                .currentTimeMillis())));
```

may be you are getting wrong time in json